# How to check whether the count is increased or not using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='filter-row']/div[2]"));

String text = element.getText(); // 7 humans
```

How can I read the number 7 only from that text

Comment: is that difficult to do? do you always want to extract 7 from the context? like what you are asking for should achievable by google/stack overflow search. explain where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for parsing number from a text:

```
String numberFromText = text.replaceAll("\\D+", ""); // removes all non-numerical characters from text
```

If you need the value as int/long then do one of the followings:

```
int totalHuman = Integer.valueOf(numberFromText);
```

or

```
long totalHuman = Long.valueOf(numberFromText);
```